# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - x}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sec^2 x-1}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sec^2x\tan x}{6x}\\
=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=\frac{1}{3}\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sec^2x}{1}=\frac{1}{3}$$

My question is about the last line. Why do they set the two expressions $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ and $\frac{\sec^2x}{1}$ equal to each other and why is the one-third in both sets of expressions, instead of multiplying the two expressions? Also what happens to the $x$ under the $\sec^2x$?

Comment: Why do you stop understanding L'Hopital halfway through?

Comment: I see where I made an error. I did not see $sec^2\ (0)=1$.

Comment: MathJax tip: common functions such as trig functions can be written using the format `\functionName` (e.g. `\tan` and `\sec`) which automatically applies proper spacing before and after it. Also, use the format `$$ ... $$` for display style formatting so you don't need to write out `\Large` or `\lim\limits`. See also [edit]s.

Comment: I want to point out one thing,(not related to your doubt or method) that the solution is extremely short if you use expansion on $\tan{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't say $\dfrac{\tan x} x$ is equal to $\dfrac{\sec^2 x} 1;$ rather it says $\lim\limits_{x\to0} \dfrac{\tan x} x = \lim\limits_{x\to0} \dfrac{\sec^2 x} 1.$

Their limits as  $x\to0$ are equal; the functions themselves are not.

The reason for the conclusion that they are equal is the same as the reason for the equalities in $$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sec^2 x-1}{3x^2} =\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sec^2x\tan x}{6x}. $$
That reason is **L'Hopital's rule.**

The next equality after that is not deduced from L'Hopital's rule, but from the equality $$ \lim_{x\to0} \sec^2 x = 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of applying L'Hopital's Rule, which is just plain silly. Of course that$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x=\tan'(0)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

They have used [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).